# Is it possible to use ViewModel with a Dialog class?

Tags: android

Our project has an Input Method Service. It is a custom keyboard where we call a Dialog to show some screens where the user is able to interact.

My question is:

Is it possible for a ViewModel to be used with Dialog class as we do it with Activity ?

Comment: "Is it possible..." questions almost always have "yes" as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Viewmodel if your dialog extends a DialogFragment class. Viewmodels can be used with both activities and fragments.